# NavigationService cant be used?

Tags: c#, service, navigation, windows-phone

I am building this application that will give the user some information based on the user's name, age and location.

If the application is launched for the first time, i want to redirect the user to FirstTimePage.xaml where he can save his name, age and location.

if the user isnt opening the application for the first time, the application retrieves the name, age and location from Isolated Storage so there is no need to go to the FirstTimePage.xaml

Currently, I am checking on MainPage.xaml if the data on Isolated storage exist. If they exist, the user stays on MainPage.xaml. If they dont exist, the user is redirected to FirstTimePage.xaml.

My problem:

The first time the user will open the application, even if they are redirected to FirstTimePage.xaml, for a few frames they see the MainPage.xaml. Not even a second, but it is a little ugly. So I tried to put the "checking" code to app.xaml.cs (inside the codeblock that is executed when the application is launched)

The thing is that it doesnt recognises the Navigation code. It gives me an error at the bold word "NavigationService.Navigate...."

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Why not start off first by showing code that you currently have what you have explained here is fine but you know the architecture of this code perhaps sharing some of the relevant code would yield in getting better results in regards to help and or recommendations in helping you achieve your goals

Comment: The application always starts on MainPage.xaml.

In the Loaded event on the MainPage, I have this code:

if (!Settings.appSettings.Contains("SetupDone"))
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ftPages/EN/ftPage1EN.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                Calculations();
                //Display_Log() is executed within Calculations().
            }

So that if its the first time the app launches, the user will be redirected to anothe page. However, for a few frames I still see the MainPage.xaml. Why?

Comment: this is hard to read you should place that in the original question for readability

Comment: http://pastebin.com/N6Av7u2R

This is on the Loaded event on MainPage.xaml

It checks if it is the first time the application is launched by checking on IsolatedStorageSettinngs. If it is the first time, the user is redirected to Fpage.xaml. The problem is that for a few frames, less than a second the user will see the main page. Is there any way to make this not happen?

Comment: when you post code you need to paste in the full method where the code resides on that link you posted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to control navigation you need to call the `Application.Current.RootFrame` to gain access to the `NavigationService` prior to a page actually being loaded.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
            //Logic should go here to determine what page needs to load
            Uri nUri = new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(nUri);

    }
```

See: [Setting the start page](http://debugmode.net/2011/09/05/setting-start-page-of-windows-phone-dynamically-through-code/) for a more in depth discussion.